# Mysql table keeps crashing. How to debug the cause and prevent it?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, myisam

My wordpress wp_users table keeps crashing and when I get up on the morning is : wp_users' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

So all my users can't access the site. If I do a manuall repair it works but then after some time it crashes again.

How can I debug it? I read somewhere that could be hd space but I got plenty of it

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        44G  7.9G   36G  19% /
devtmpfs        994M     0  994M   0% /dev
tmpfs           996M     0  996M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           996M  101M  896M  11% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           996M     0  996M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Comment: Check your syslog for evidence of filesystem corruption.

Comment: Repair, mysqldump table, drop table, reload table from dump

Comment: Maybe the OS crashed/rebooted uncleanly? What is your uptime?

Comment: I changed from myisam to innodb to see if that helps. I will update tomorrow will results

Comment: I don't think altering the table from myisam to innodb will solve it. Check the MySQL error log, system log, and dmesg for any issues.

Comment: Well so far it didn't block nor crash again. I followed instructions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869377/mysql-table-is-marked-as-crashed which says that InnoDB has crash recovery built into the Storage Engine's initialization. MyISAM does not